# Ember.js AJAX Model

Tags: model, ember.js

I am a CodeIgniter dev and I am trying to learn ember.js.

I have been trying to get a model together which will make an AJAX call to a server, pull in a XML file, parse the data and return it.

The following is my model code:

```
App.Statement = Ember.Object.extend();
App.Statement.reopenClass({
    all: function() {
        var transactions = {};
        // FROM: http://jquerybyexample.blogspot.com/2012/04/read-and-process-xml-using-jquery-ajax.html
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://www.example.com/transactions.xml",
            dataType: "xml",
            success: function(xml){
                $(xml).find('transaction').each(function(i,v){
                    transactions[i].id      = $(this).attr('id');
                    transactions[i].vendor  = $(this).find('vendor').text();
                    transactions[i].date    = $(this).find('date').text();
                    transactions[i].spent   = $(this).find('spent').text();
                });
            },
            error: function() {
                console.log("An error occurred while processing XML file.");
            }
        });
        return transactions;
    }
});
```

The following is the content of my XML file (transactions.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<statement>
    <transaction id="123456">
        <vendor>WH Smiths</vendor>
        <date>2013-05-01</date>
        <spent>10.00</spent>
    </transaction>
    <transaction id="123457">
        <vendor>Gap</vendor>
        <date>2013-05-02</date>
        <spent>39.99</spent>
    </transaction>
    <transaction id="123458">
        <vendor>DSG PLC</vendor>
        <date>2013-05-03</date>
        <spent>1024.99</spent>
    </transaction>
    <transaction id="123459">
        <vendor>Tesco</vendor>
        <date>2013-05-06</date>
        <spent>23.35</spent>
    </transaction>
</statement>
```

When I use the console to try to access the transactions object it remains undefined can anyone point me in the right direction?

---

**UPDATE:**

Okay, so based on the replys so far my model now looks like this:

```
var transaction = Ember.ArrayProxy.create({content: []});

App.Statement = DS.Model.extend({
    all: function() {
        var transactions = {};
        // FROM: http://jquerybyexample.blogspot.com/2012/04/read-and-process-xml-using-jquery-ajax.html
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://www.atwright.co.uk/cof/statement.xml",
            dataType: "xml",
            success: function(xml){
                var obj = Ember.Object.create({id:null, vendor:null, date:null, spent:null});
                obj.setProperties({
                    id: $(this).attr('id'), 
                    vendor: $(this).find('vendor').text(), 
                    date: $(this).find('date').text(), 
                    spent: $(this).find('spent').text()
                });
                transaction.pushObject(obj);
            },
            error: function() {
                console.log("An error occurred while processing XML file.");
            }
        });
        return transactions;
    }
});
```

How do I access any of the data? I can see that transaction has many Ember related properties but no data within it (though I could be doing it wrong).

Comment: You don't seem to be storing the transactions variable anywhere..
Because the AJAX request is async, you need to store the transactions somewhere, the ember convention is to store them on a `model` variable on the controller EDIT: just saw you're doing the AJAX inside the model

Comment: I have had to put this on hold for now -- so I will mark an answer when I am able to test etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the problem (besides the async peculiarities) with `var transactions = {};` is that you are just creating a plain javascript object, which has no Ember support whatsoever, by Ember support I mean that you can bind to etc.

Try to declare you transaction variable like this:

```
var transaction = Ember.ArrayProxy.create({content: []});
```

And then inside your success function where you iterate over the results *(code not testet)*:

```
...
var obj = Ember.Object.create({id:null, vendor:null, date:null, spent:null});
obj.setProperties({
  id: $(this).attr('id'), 
  vendor: $(this).find('vendor').text(), 
  date: $(this).find('date').text(), 
  spent: $(this).find('spent').text()
});
transaction.pushObject(obj);
...
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

`$.ajax` call is asynchronous, so when the method returns, it is returning transactions as an empty object. That may be what you are seeing in the console.

In addition most Ember apps that retrieve a collection of records return them as an array. This is useful because an `ArrayController` can easily observe the contents of the array for rendering purposes.

Comment: Does Ember make it so that JS arrays can be multi-dimensional?
I am probably doing the whole thing wrong because I am a PHP guy and JS looks like PHP but seems to have many subtle differences. :S

Comment: @LukeMelia I see some parallelism between you answer and mine, just for curiosity, would the async behavior be played out if `transaction` where specified as an ember `ArrayProxy`?

Comment: @atwright147 a JS array is single dimensional array. Ember useful methods on Array that make them observable, but does not change the basic nature. In JS, `{}` is NOT an array.

Comment: @intuitivepixel using an ArrayProxy here is definitely an approach that could work.

Answer (score -1):

You don't have a model here, because you're extending `Ember.Object` instead of `DS.Model`. Instead, you probably want something like:

```
App.Statement = DS.Model.extend({
    // Ajax stuff goes here.
});
```

See the [Defining Models guide](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/defining-models/) for more information. You may also want to look at [Creating Custom Transformations](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/the-rest-adapter/) rather than performing the transformations directly in your XHR request.